# How to loop through object with array with object syntax?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I would like to loop through my object with object syntax - foreach .. $prop->val but I get an error that it is not an object.

Here is my object:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [calls] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [employee_id] => 47
                    [call_duration] => 10
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [employee_id] => 47
                    [call_duration] => 10
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [employee_id] => 47
                    [call_duration] => 137
                )
```

It was created like this:

```
$all_calls->calls[] = [
   'employee_id' => $employee_id,
   'call_duration'  => $value->duration
];
```

How can I loop through "calls" without using array syntax $call["employee_id"] but instead $call->employee_id?

Comment: you can cast your array to an object using `$call = (object) $call`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edited]
I have made same object that you have mentioned and working fine for me;

check below code.

```
<?php
$all_calls = new stdClass;

$all_calls->calls = [
    (object)['employee_id' => 47, 'call_duration'  => 10],
    (object)['employee_id' => 47, 'call_duration'  => 10],
    (object)['employee_id' => 47, 'call_duration'  => 137],
];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($all_calls);


foreach($all_calls->calls as $call) {
    $employee_id = $call->employee_id;
}
```

Comment: That gives me
Trying to get property 'employee_id' of non-object

Comment: Edited my answer; used same object that you have made and it gives me correct output.

Comment: How would you later add another entry to calls?

Comment: didn't get you; can you please explain more.

Comment: Like if it was inside a loop and I wanted to add calls one by one... each time I add one entry with employee_id and call_duration.

Comment: Like this.. . but it only overwrites it... instead of adds.. :( $all_calls->calls = [
                (object)['employee_id' => 47, 'call_duration'  => 10]
            ];

            $all_calls->calls = [
                (object)['employee_id' => 047, 'call_duration'  => 100]
            ];

Comment: Try this; 
$all_calls->calls[] = [ (object)['employee_id' => 47, 'call_duration' => 10] ];
$all_calls->calls[] = [ (object)['employee_id' => 47, 'call_duration' => 100] ];

Comment: Trying to get property employee_id of non-object

Comment: Oh my mistake, Try this; 
$all_calls->calls[] = (object)['employee_id' => 47, 'call_duration' => 10]; $all_calls->calls[] = (object)['employee_id' => 47, 'call_duration' => 100];

Comment: Perfect, you saved my day! :)

Answer (score 1):

based on how you create the array of calls, you can do this to iterate over your calls and use them as objects :

```
foreach($all_calls->calls as $call) {
    $call = (object)$call; // cast the array as an object
    $employeeId = $call->employee_id;
}
```

On line 2, the associative array will be converted to an object with properties named by keys and corresponding values

reference here : http://php.net/manual/language.types.object.php

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't actually have an array of **objects** but instead an array of **key => value** pairs when you do

```
$all_calls->calls[] = [
   'employee_id' => $employee_id,
   'call_duration'  => $value->duration
];
```

you will of course not be able to access the members as objects.

You *can* cast the **key => value** array to an object when you fetch it, but the more correct thing, especially if you want the entire object structure look like your example is to add instances of **stdClass** instead of **key => value** pair arrays to the `$calls` array from the start. Otherwise, your object will still contain arrays of **key => value** pairs that you just cast when you want to use them.

You could do something like

```
$c = new stdClass();
$c->employee_id = 10;
$c->call_duration = 60;
$obj->calls[] = $c
```

But to make it a bit more compact and not have to type so much you could do something like.

```
$obj->calls[] = (object)['employee_id' => 10, 'call_duration' => 42];
```

This will make your `$calls` member variable to contain instances of **stdClass Object** whose members can be accessed with **->**.

One can also accomplish the same by having the initial data in json format and doing a `jsondecode` similar to

```
$obj->calls[] = json_decode('{ "employee_id ": 10, "call_duration": 60 }');
```

But the other solution is a bit more clear to me.

Comment: Thank you that's what I was looking for.